# Image Magick - How to compress for Google page speed?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to find the right command for compressing png and jpg files good enough for Google Page speed.

I'm using the following from my OSX termial:

```
convert -strip -quality 85 imagesource.png imagesource_optimized.png
```

The result is no difference in file size between the original and "optimized version. Am Is there a different command I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compression is fundamentally different between PNG and JPEG because PNG is lossless and JPEG is lossy.

With a `JPEG` the `-quality` parameter specifies how much quality should be retained.

With a `PNG` file, the `-quality` parameter specifies the strategy and the amount of time/effort `zlib` can spend to optimise your image - think `gzip --best` versus `gzip --fast.`

See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality

For PNG, I suggest `pngcrush` which you can install with `homebrew` using:

```
brew install pngcrush
```

For JPEG, either use `-quality` or specify a maximum size:

```
# Specify by quality
convert input.jpg -strip -quality 75% output.jpg

# Specify maximum size
convert input.jpg -strip -define jpeg:extent=300k output.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Compression is fundamentally different between PNG and JPEG because PNG is lossless and JPEG is lossy.