# How accurate can I adjust the jpg file size in python-pillow？

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to upload some pictures while there is a limitation of picture file size about 300 kB.

So I get the raw file width & height, then calculate the ratio.

I use pillow to convert/reduce the jpg file size.

The raw file size is 3655 kB at 3072 x 4568 96dpi, 96dpi, 24bit.
I set new file size as 2816 x 4187, and check, that the dpi and bit depth is the same.

But the new_file size is 923 kB which is far from my expectation (should be 3 MB).

I wonder how to accurately adjust the jpg file size in python-pillow.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

def img_type(suffix):
    if suffix == '.jpg' or suffix == '.JPG'or suffix == '.jpeg':
        imgtype = 'jpeg'
    else :
        imgtype = 'png'
    return(imgtype)
def processImage(imagefile,tar_size, imgtype):
    f=Path(imagefile)
    im = Image.open(imagefile)
    width, height = im.size
    current_size = os.path.getsize(imagefile)  # 原图文件大小
    #current_size = os.stat(imagefile).st_size
    print(f'current_size ={current_size}')  #3655KB =  3742579B
    print(f'tar_size={tar_size}')
    if current_size < tar_size:
        pass
    else:
        ratio = (current_size/tar_size)**0.5
        print(f'ratio={ratio}')
        print(f'x={width} y={height}')
        new_x=int(width/ratio)
        new_y=int(height/ratio)
        print(f'x={new_x}y={new_y}')
        new_im = im.resize((new_x,new_y))
        #im.thumbnail((new_x, new_y))
        new_img=f.stem+'_resize'+f.suffix
        imgtype = img_type(f.suffix)
        new_im.save(new_img, imgtype)

def test():
    folder = r'D:\code_prj\Med_OCR\data'
    p=Path(folder)
    extensions = ["*.JPG", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.PNG"]
    target_size = 3*1024*1024 #3MB
    for extension in extensions:
        for file in p.rglob(extension):
            processImage(file,target_size,extension)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Try to use an approriate quality level `img.save('test.jpg', quality=95)`. A quality level of 95 is high whereas a lower quality level saves files size. JPEG files are not bitmap files, where half of the pixels means half the file size.

Comment: With Python https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621

Comment: With ImageMagick https://stackoverflow.com/a/52152070/2836621

Comment: With lots of files https://stackoverflow.com/a/64411598/2836621